# Xamarin Forms: hiding the scrollbar in a ListView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there an easy way to hide the scrollbar in a ListView, but still leave it scrollable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make a custom ListView renderers for each platform (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/):

On Android:

```
ListView.VericalScrollbarEnabled = false;
```

On iOS:

```
UIScrollView.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
```

Comment: Thanks! One more thing - can I change the color of the separator between the listview items and if yes what is the name of the property?

Comment: No problem. iOS: UIScrollView.SeparatorColor, Android: ListView(this).Divider = new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue); ListView.DividerHeight(1);

Comment: As for your question about separator color (comments above) in ListView - Xamarin team recommend to use build-in bindable property [SeparatorColor](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.SeparatorColorProperty/).

Comment: You can also do this by using an effect. This way you don't need to create a complete customer renderer for scrollviews. The effect can set the same properties as in this answer

Comment: Hi, I am try to write custom renderer for hide scrollbar in listview. I am try to write above line in andorid 'onelementchanged' property but not luck. Please suggest where can i write this line for getting hide the scrollbar in listview in both andorid and ios in xamarin.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to provide VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" in your xaml.

```
<ListView x:Name="lst"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
</ListView>
```