# How to hide scrollbar in listview in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to hide listview scrollbar in my xamarin andorid and xamarin ios application's. I have searched many post's but only few post's are having the helpful that to not clear. Please suggest any idea of hide scrollbar in listview.

Comment: This is an duplicated question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067257/xamarin-forms-hiding-the-scrollbar-in-a-listview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I did:

Android custom renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomListView),typeof(CustomListViewRenderer))]
namespace ImageList.Droid
{
    public class CustomListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control != null)
            {
                Control.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

iOS custom renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomListView), typeof(CustomListViewRenderer))]
namespace ImageList.iOS
{
    public class CustomListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Remember:*** We need to use the Custom ListView instead of the native ListView in the PCL Forms

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: Now from Xamarin.Forms version 3.5.0, we can use VerticalScrollBarVisibility, HorizontalScrollBarVisibility properties to handle ListView ScrollBarVisibility.

You can also find full source code and document from http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.com/2019/03/hide-listview-scrollbar-in-xamarinforms.html

Answer (score 0):

Custom renders for the solution here, check official documents for that
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/listview/

Android:

```
ListView.VericalScrollbarEnabled = false;
```

iOS:

```
UIScrollView.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
```

Comment: Hi shiwanka, Thanks for your answer. Can you please write some what detail. I have tried above code in onelementchanged override method but not luck. where we write above code please.

Comment: Hi deepak, this is actually custom renders, android and ios having different behaviors.... for achieve that you have to right custom renders in ios and android project level, not in pcl