# How to hide the scrollbar in listview

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to hide the scrollbar in list view, I followed  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067257/xamarin-forms-hiding-the-scrollbar-in-a-listview%22), But I am getting the following error

> ListView does not contain definition for VerticalScrollbarEnabled

Here is what I did:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.ListView), typeof(CustomListView))]

namespace MyApp.Droid.Renderer
{
    class CustomListView:ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Xamarin.Forms.ListView.VericalScrollbarEnabled = false;          

        }        
    }
}
```

How to give this property for ListView.

Comment: try Control.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set `VerticalScrollBarEnabled` on the native control, not the Forms' based one:

```
class CustomListView : ListViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
            Control.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your layout file

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

This should probably work.